# To cache or not to cache a ReadOnlyWrapper object?

Tags: design

I have a system with a structure like this:

[image]

The `ConcreteWriteable` is caching the `ReadOnlyWrapper`.

This is a similar system to what .Net's `System.Array` uses for its `Array.AsReadOnly<T>(T[] array)` method (ignoring for the moment that `System.Array`'s `AsReadOnly` is static). However looking at the code for `System.Array` at reference source, `System.Array.AsReadOnly` is returning a new wrapper each time, whereas I'm creating the wrapper at the same time as the `ConcreteWriteable` and caching it, then returning the same one each time.

This got me thinking, is there some reason why I shouldn't be doing this? Is there some reason why creating a new wrapper each time is more desirable than returning the same wrapper (bearing in mind that the wrapper cannot possibly change the `ConcreteWriteable` and is indeed a wrapper, not a copy)?

Answer (score 1):

If the wrapper is truly immutable, program behavior is identical whether you create a new wrapper each time, or reuse one. The only difference is the thrashing of the garbage collector.

I have thought about using structs as read-only collection wrappers, instead of class instances, but I realized there would be little gain, since often a collection is cast as a collection interface, which would box the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Do not cache.

Technically: As Frank already said, the difference is the garbage collector. If you cache it, your objects will be moved to the java oldspace, where trashing objects is slow and painful. Whereas trashing objects in the new object space, comes at no costs, because this element isn't simply touched any more. But if you keep objects for no reason, this object is copied from one half of the new object space to the other, because there is a path to this object - The VM assumes: It must be important enough to keep. The object is aging in the new space and copied each time, where it produces (copying) costs. Thus caching objects produces costs by living on and they are much more expensive to clean up, after they reach oldspace.

Design: Always let the consumer of your API decide, how long an object must live. You as a designer, you don't have this information when designing the API/class.

Premature Optimization: You should also avoid premature optimization. Not every caching is a big gain. Do optimizations, when there is a good reason to, but avoid it if it makes code less readable with no much gain - avoid microoptimizations. If you need a caching instance, don't do it by default, but provide a "factory" providing caching objects, which contains the caching code. Your VM will come with new optimization strategies each time you get a newer one. If you need speed - it is mostly better to choose better algorithms instead of using microoptimizations.

Creating Objects: Last but not least, the "new" operation is not very expensive. There is no need to avoid that.

Comment: I can't accept this answer for several reasons I'm afraid. Firstly, your first paragraph is very Java-specific. The point about how the garbage collector behaves is valid, but I cannot assume all garbage collectors behave the same way as Java's. Secondly, the new operation is cheap, until it's called in a loop and suddenly there are thousands of readonly wrappers floating around that could all be a single instance. Thirdly, a factory seems overkill.

Comment: Thank you for your feefback, I understand your concerns about the java-specific-answer thing. But why do you assume, that other systems using a garbage collector, won't duplicate successfull memory management strategies. Well, I do not know much about other implementations - you are correct about that. But if someone uses your method in a loop, it is left up to him, to implement any kind of better solution - or he doesn't need it. The factory using a pool can be either implemented by you or the consumer of your API. Anyway, thank you since I could thought about this topic for a while.

Comment: I don't assume they don't implement successful memory management strategies, but there's more than one way to successfully manage memory. I see no reason to assume all GCs copy the JVM's GC. Aside from which, I'm not even assuming there is a GC involved. Lazy initialisation might be more suitable than a full factory class in this case since `AsReadOnly` is already similar to a factory method. Out of interest the architecture I chose in the end was slightly different.